# How does Azure App Service decide whether my app active or idle?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, event-handling

I'm trying to find information what are the criteria for that? I know that "Always On" option exists and calls periodically the service to keep it alive.

So my question:
Is it only REST calls to an endpoint shows that service in active? If I have a Kafka consumer that receive the messages, is it considered as the app is not idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web app can time out after 20 minutes of inactivity, and only requests to the actual web app can reset the timer. Viewing the app's configuration in the Azure portal or making requests to the advanced tools site (`https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`) doesn't reset the timer. If you set the web app that hosts your job to run continuously, run on a schedule, or use event-driven triggers, enable the Always on setting on your web app's Azure Configuration page.

**WebJobs** is designed for background processing. You can do as much background processing as you want in a WebJob. For more information about WebJobs, see [Run background tasks with WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create).